# How to get current JsonSerializerOptions in ASP.NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, system.text.json

I use System.Text.Json and I set JsonSerializerOptions in ConfigureServices method of Startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 { 
 ...
            services.AddControllers()
                    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                    {
                        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
                    });
 ...
 }
```

Now I want get current JsonSerializerOptions in CustomErrorHandlingMiddleware

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
      try
      {
          await _next(context);
      }
      catch (Exception exc)
      {
          var response = new SomeObject(); 
                
          var currentJsonSerializerOptions = ? //I want get CurrentJsonSerializerOptions here

          var result = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(response, currentJsonSerializerOptions);

          context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
          context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
          await context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
      }
}
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could inject `IOptions<JsonOptions>` or `IOptionsSnapshot<JsonOptions>` as per [Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1) into your middleware.

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, IOptions<JsonOptions> options)
{
    JsonSerializerOptions serializerOptions = options.Value.JsonSerializerOptions;

    await _next(httpContext);
}
```

Comment: Hi, friend.Thanks you for answer. I try this solution, but injected neither IOptions<JsonSerializerOptions> nor IOptionsSnapshot<JsonSerializerOptions>' value  are not the same that I set in Startup.cs. For example I set "JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase", but when inject IOptions<JsonSerializerOptions> (or IOptionsSnapshot<JsonSerializerOptions>) PropertyNamingPolicy's value is null

Comment: @RamilAliyev Sorry I got the type wrong, try updated.

Comment: Additional note: it must be Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonOptions. Because there is also exist Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json.JsonOptions

Comment: @sepulka both seems to work for me. Do you know what the difference is?

Comment: @Zero3,  one for newtonsoft json, second for System.Text.Json. Different classes for different libraries, but with same functionality.

Comment: @sepulka I'm pretty sure that Json.NET (Newtonsoft) does not ship with classes in the `Microsoft.*` namespace.

Comment: @Zero3 the one under `Http` namespace is for HTTP extensions, such as reading JSON content from a request or response. Conversely, the one under `Mvc` namespace is for MVC formatters used by the controllers. In this answer, it was the one under `Mvc` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a middleware class that inherits from ***ActionResult*** as follows

```
public override Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
        {
            var httpContext = context.HttpContext;
            var response    = httpContext.Response;
            response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            response.StatusCode  = (int) _statusCode;

            var options = httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<JsonOptions>>().Value;

            return JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(response.Body, _result, _result.GetType(), options.JsonSerializerOptions);
        }
```